# How to configure SELinux to allow specific services to communicate with Avahi?

Tags: fedora, selinux, avahi, fedora-20

I have a service, running on a Fedora 20 machine, that when started attempts to register services with Avahi. This works perfectly if my service is started while SELinux is in permissive mode, but the service will not register when SELinux is enforcing.

I am aware of the `httpd_dbus_avahi` boolean in SELinux. This works perfectly to allow Apache to register services, but I have been unable to find much information about how to allow other  specific services to communicate with Avahi.

More specifically I am attempting to allow tvheadend to register its HTSP service with Avahi, but I am also curious how any particular service can be allowed to communicate with Avahi without being stopped by SELinux. I am NOT interested in turning off SELinux or making the process permissive that wants to communicate with Avahi.

---

**EDIT:** added all SELinux and service unit information relating to tvheadend

**---SELinux---**

**audit.log messages**

After executing `semodule -DB` and restarting the tvheadend service. The following are all messages that appeared in the audit log. The last message seems like the problem, but I am not sure what to make of it...

```
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1393282994.012:512): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm="tvheadend" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1393283083.635:513): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm="tvheadend" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1393283084.291:514): pid=752 uid=81 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='avc:  denied  { send_msg } for msgtype=method_return dest=:1.114 spid=731 tpid=14478 scontext=system_u:system_r:avahi_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tclass=dbus  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=81 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

**Process**

Output from `ps -AZ | grep tvheadend`

```
system_u:system_r:init_t:s0      2599 ?        00:00:06 tvheadend
```

I noticed that the `init_t` process type seems a little strange since all other services on my system have the `initrc_t` process type. I am not sure why the tvheadend service is different in this way.

**User**

Output from `sudo -u hts id`

```
uid=1001(hts) gid=1003(hts) groups=1003(hts),39(video) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

I use this user only for running the tvheadend service. This user has a home directory on a separate partition much larger than the system partition since DVR files generated by tvheadend can become quite large.

When I created this user I did not use the `--system` switch with the `useradd` command. Perhaps I should have?

**Executable**

Output from `ls -Z /usr/local/bin | grep tvheadend`

```
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       tvheadend
```

**---Service---**

**Unit File**

```
[Unit]
Description=TVHeadEnd
After=syslog.target network.target avahi-daemon.service sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb0.demux0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb0.dvr0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb0.frontend0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb0.net0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb1.demux0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb1.dvr0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb1.frontend0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb1.net0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-video4linux-vbi0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-video4linux-vbi1.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-video4linux-video0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-video4linux-video1.device
Wants=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb0.demux0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb0.dvr0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb0.frontend0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb0.net0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb1.demux0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb1.dvr0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb1.frontend0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-dvb-dvb1.net0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-video4linux-vbi0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-video4linux-vbi1.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-video4linux-video0.device sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:05:00.0-video4linux-video1.device

[Service]
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=no
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/tvheadend
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/tvheadend -f -u $TVH_USER -g $TVH_GROUP -p $TVH_PID -b $TVH_ADDRESS --http_port $TVH_HTTP_PORT --htsp_port $TVH_HTSP_PORT
PIDFile=$TVH_PID
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Unit Environment File**

```
TVH_USER=hts

TVH_GROUP=hts

TVH_PID=/var/run/tvheadend.pid

TVH_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0

TVH_HTTP_PORT=9981

TVH_HTSP_PORT=9982
```

Comment: Did you look at the audit log? See also [SELinux Troubleshooting](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting.html) in the Red Hat documentation.

Comment: Can you do `ps -AZ | grep tvheadend` to figure out what context this process runs in?

Comment: `ps -AZ | grep tvheadend` outputs `system_u:system_r:init_t:s0      2599 ?        00:00:06 tvheadend`. I updated the question to include this information and much more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running this service as `init_t` is probably not a great idea.

The reason you get this behaviour is because `tvheadend` is *probably* labelled `bin_t`, and no transition rule exists to move a file of this type out of the `init_t` context.

You can search this to know for sure..

```
$ sesearch -s init_t --type -c process | grep bin_t
```

This command returns no results. No transitions out of init_t for a `bin_t` process.

You should also avoid running this type in `initrc_t` too since its not appropriate for the service. As a general matter of fact -- the *best* solution would be to properly write a confined policy for you're service, however this is beyond the scope of this answer.

Instead, you need to get your process out of `init_t` to another type. Because no policy exists for this application it is probably best to move this into `unconfined_t`, for which a type transition does exist.

```
$ sesearch -s init_t --type -c process -t unconfined_exec_t
Found 1 semantic te rules:
   type_transition init_t unconfined_exec_t : process unconfined_t;
```

We can also check that the rule that is being hit in policy will not get hit in `unconfined_t` (which it shouldn't).

```
$ sesearch -s avahi_t -p send_msg -c dbus -t unconfined_t --allow
Found 2 semantic av rules:
   allow avahi_t unconfined_t : dbus send_msg ; 
   allow system_bus_type unconfined_t : dbus send_msg ;
```

To do this, simply relabel your `tvheadend` program to `unconfined_exec_t`.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t unconfined_exec_t -f f /usr/bin/tvheadend
```

Then restore.

```
restorecon /usr/bin/tvheadend
```

Now, re-running your service *should* work. If you re-run `ps -AZ | grep tvheadend` you should see your process running in `unconfined_t`.

Ideally a new policy should be used for this program, but if no policy exists its best to run it without policy at all in the `unconfined_t` domain. `initrc_t` and `init_t` are not really meant to be used to run services (although some do incorrectly go in there), `initrc_t` was originally conceived to run SYSV shell scripts and `init_t` is meant for running systemd/init itself.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and works exactly as you describe! Thanks much for the very informative answer!

Comment: There's a [danwalsh blog post](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/70577.html) with some context as well.  It explains why `initrc_t` would be  a bad idea, and endorses using a newly added type `unconfined_service_t`.  (But if you don't have that type, it sounds like `unconfined_t` is preferable).

Answer (score 4):

The manpage for `apache_selinux` mentions that `# semanage permissive` can be used to allow specific processes to run in *permissive* mode.

```
# semanage permissive -a avahi_t
```

I suggest finding some more detailed info on its usage

## Though, it might be wise to find a better solution than simply "allowing a service permissive" access controls;

especially when SELinux provides a vast number of config options to allow a given service permissions to do *only* the things you *expect* it to do, and nothing more!
 Because of this vast number of control options, however, admins have to learn what options exist, and decide how/when/where to implement them efficaciously.  As I mentioned, the first place to look is within the manpages on your system, as well as your audit log in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.  To search for messages about avahi, for example, within your log files, execute:

```
# grep /usr/sbin/avahi /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

---

**EDIT:** to reflect updated question

```sh
msg=avc: denied { send_msg } for msgtype=method_return dest=:1.114
spid=731 tpid=14478 scontext=system_u:system_r:avahi_t:s0 
tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0
```

## Take a look at the Manpages

The following items in particular should be of interest to you:

- `system_dbusd_t` SELinux Type:

  ```
  $ man system_dbusd_selinux
  ```
- `avahi_t` SELinux Type:

  ```
  $ man avahi_selinux
  ```

  - take a look at the `avahi_exec_t`
  - `avahi_initrc_exec_t` file contexts
  - `avahi_var_run_t`
  - `avahi_unit_file_t`
  - as well as the list of related **booleans** therein.

---

Allright, as I'm not sure that you've noticed that last bit on `avahi_exec_t`; and since I can't post comments :/ yet; here's the pertinent info from the manpage itself:

> SELinux defines the file context types for the avahi, if you wanted to
>   store files with these  types  in  a  diffent
>          paths,  you  need  to execute the semanage command to sepecify alternate labeling and then use restorecon to put the
>          labels on disk.
>
> ```
>    semanage fcontext -a -t avahi_exec_t '/srv/avahi/content(/.*)?'
>    restorecon -R -v /srv/myavahi_content
>
>    Note: SELinux often uses regular expressions to specify labels that match multiple files.
>
>    The following file types are defined for avahi:
>
>    avahi_exec_t
>
>    - Set files with the avahi_exec_t type, if you want to transition an executable to the avahi_t domain.
>
>    Paths:
>         /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon, /usr/sbin/avahi-autoipd, /usr/sbin/avahi-dnsconfd
>
>    avahi_initrc_exec_t
>
>    - Set files with the avahi_initrc_exec_t type, if you want to transition an executable to the avahi_initrc_t domain.
>
>    avahi_unit_file_t
>
>    - Set files with the avahi_unit_file_t type, if you want to treat the files as avahi unit content.
> ```

---

## SELinux and Process Transitions

Head over to [Dan Walsh's blog](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/42394.html) for some detailed discussion/information on SELinux, this post in particular mentions

> A process transition says when process running as label a_t executes a file labeled b_exec_t it should execute the process as b_t  An example of this would be service httpd start.  In this case we have unconfined_t running an init script labeled initrc_exec_t and SELinux starts the process as initrc_t.

Aside from that, your best bet is to keep researching the `tvheadend` program, as well as SELinux management.  You can create a **custom policy** as suggested by the `audit` log messages; something like:

```
# grep tvheadend /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp
```

At least until a better solutions comes across, and/or `tvheadend` makes its way to the fedora repos.  Lastly, take a better look at the unit file (service file) you created for `systemd`; check for errors, potential additions and changes.

Comment: I agree and would prefer to not allow the process to run in permissive mode. I have edited my question to include relevant audit.log messages.

Comment: I also noticed the "source context" `avahi_t` is not being allowed `send_msg` for target process with context `init_t`. There are only 2 processes running on my system with context `init_t`, systemd and tvheadend. All other processes run as `initrc_t` could this be my problem? Unfortunately I am not sure why the tvheadend process has type `init_t` and not `initrc_t`. I have been reading how processes types work, but have not found my answer yet. I have added much information to my original question that may be helpful in figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

You could fix this using [audit2allow](http://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow) to create a custom policy module

```
audit2allow -M custom_avhi <file_containing_AVC-denied messages
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i custom_avhi.pp
```

Comment: This does easily fix the problem without making anything run permissive. The htsp service is correctly registered with avahi if `avahi_t` processes are allowed `send_msg` to `init_t` processes. However, I believe it should be possible to make this work without adding any new modules to SELinux. Perhaps making tvheadend's process run as type `initrc_t`. If I can't figure out how to make that happen I will accept this answer.